# How to add an URL to a cron job on my server?

Tags: php, command-line, ssh, cron

What i'm trying to do is to execute an URL once every 5 minutes, it's for an update to the database:

so first i'm accessing the crontab:

`crontab -e`

then i add to the existing list this line:

`5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.example.com/index.php/update`

and i checked the DB after 5 minutes but there's no updating info.
What is that i'm doing wrong? did i skip a step without knowing?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: i think it should be `*/5` at the start.. had the same problem with my cron job

Comment: @RyanHurling - yup.  That leading 5 means on the fifth minute of every hour.

Comment: thought so ill move it into an answer for the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `5 * * * *` to `*/5 * * * *` and it will run the cron job every 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

1 : Check `/var/log/syslog` where you can se if the cronjob actually had been executed (not nessecarily successfully)

2 : The url looks a litte bit weird to me

> ```
> http://www.example.com/index.php/update
> ```

should maybe be (typo??)

> ```
> http://www.example.com/index.php?update
> ```

3 : As Ryan Hurling mentions,

> ```
> 5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.example.com/index.php/update
> ```

guess it should be

> ```
> */05 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.example.com/index.php/update
> ```

4 :
Tried

> ```
> */05 * * * * /usr/bin/wget curl http://www.example.com/index.php/update
> ```

??